# How to check if a Ketubah is genuine

Tags: synagogue, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, ketubah

Recently I was discussing with a friend the uses of one's parents' ketubah in everyday life. Obviously one of the main uses of a ketubah is proving one's Jewish status in order to join a Jewish community.
We wondered how synagogues, especially orthodox ones, examine whether the ketubot they're presented are genuine when given as proof of status.

Comment: tainted, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you get great answers, and that you also look around and see what else we've got that might interest you, such as other [tag:ketubah] posts. I look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: Do you assume people are going around forging accurate fake ketubas?

Comment: I should hope that no one is faking ketubot but the hypothetical situation interested me.

Comment: I'm thinking this may be primarily opinion based. To the best of my knowledge, there is a very limited amount of Halachic use that a Kesubah is needed for, and I don't believe that Synagogue membership is one of them. That leaves it in the realm of Synagogue policy, which frankly could be anything that the Synagogue decides that it wants to be.

Comment: "Obviously one of the main uses of a ketubah is proving one's Jewish status". While it may be **a** usage, I wouldn't say it's *one of the main uses*.